# Reorder files in Fineuploader - best approach?

Tags: fine-uploader

We've just implemented Fineuploader (with s3) on a project, which is working great, however in the next section we are adding it to we need to store a sort order for the images which are displayed on the front end as a gallery.

Obviously this is beyond what fineuploader was designed to do, e're wondering if anyone has done this before and has a good approach. We are thinking possible:

- Attempt to implement this within the fineuploader UI div making the LI sortable. Benefits: all other functionality built in, easiest UI experience for user. Negatives: potential conflicts?
- Alternatively: after files confirmed uploaded remove from fineuploader and into seperate list. Pros: no potential conflicts with fine uploader. Negative: more code, recreating existing nice UI, UX more complicated.

Would be really great if anyone who has had experience can point us in the right way.

many thanks,

Comment: Have you tried option 1? Seems like that would be easy to attempt, and I'm not seeing any issues off the top of my head.

Comment: Did exactly this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer this, I went for option one, made the UL sortable using jQuery sort plugin and had no problems.